# sorting a map on the basis of key and value

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

I had developed the below code in which we can sort the `Hash Map` basis on the key as well as on the basis of value also.

the main logic is that we can sort `Map`, be it `HashMap` or `Hashtable` by copying keys into `List` than sorting `List` by using `Collections.sort()` method, here you can use either `Comparator` or `Comparable` based upon whether you want to sort on custom order or natural order. Once `List` of keys are sorted, we can create another Map, particularly `LinkedHashMap` to insert keys in sorted order. `LinkedHashMap` will maintain the order on which keys are inserted, result is a sorted Map based on keys

My query is that if you cal please advise me for other better approach or any improvement you guys can suggest.

```
public class MapSortingExample {


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        //creating Hashtable for sorting
        Map<String, Integer> olympic2012 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        olympic2012.put("England", 3);
        olympic2012.put("USA", 1);
        olympic2012.put("China", 2);
        olympic2012.put("Russia", 4);
        //olympic2012.put("Australia", 4); //adding duplicate value

        //printing hashtable without sorting
        System.out.println("Unsorted Map in Java : " + olympic2012);

        //sorting Map e.g. HashMap, Hashtable by keys in Java
        Map<String, Integer> sorted = sortByKeys(olympic2012);
        System.out.println("Sorted Map in Java by key: " + sorted);


        //sorting Map like Hashtable and HashMap by values in Java
        sorted = sortByValues(olympic2012);
        System.out.println("Sorted Map in Java by values: " + sorted);


        //Sorting Map in Java by keys using TreeMap
        Map<String, Integer> sortedMapByKeys = new TreeMap<String,Integer>();
        sortedMapByKeys.putAll(olympic2012);
        System.out.println("Sorted Map in Java by key using TreeMap : " + sortedMapByKeys);


        //Sorting Map by keys in Java using Google Collections (Guava)
        //Main benefit is you can specify any ordering like natural or toString or arbitrary
        Map<String, Integer> sortingUsingGuava = Maps.newTreeMap(Ordering.natural());
        sortingUsingGuava.putAll(olympic2012);
        System.out.println("Example to sort Map in Java using Guava : " + sortingUsingGuava);



    }

    /*
     * Paramterized method to sort Map e.g. HashMap or Hashtable in Java
     * throw NullPointerException if Map contains null key
     */
    public static <K extends Comparable,V extends Comparable> Map<K,V> sortByKeys(Map<K,V> map){
        List<K> keys = new LinkedList<K>(map.keySet());
        Collections.sort(keys);

        //LinkedHashMap will keep the keys in the order they are inserted
        //which is currently sorted on natural ordering
        Map<K,V> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<K,V>();
        for(K key: keys){
            sortedMap.put(key, map.get(key));
        }

        return sortedMap;
    }

    /*
     * Java method to sort Map in Java by value e.g. HashMap or Hashtable
     * throw NullPointerException if Map contains null values
     * It also sort values even if they are duplicates
     */
    public static <K extends Comparable,V extends Comparable> Map<K,V> sortByValues(Map<K,V> map){
        List<Map.Entry<K,V>> entries = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<K,V>>(map.entrySet());

        Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Map.Entry<K,V>>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Entry<K, V> o1, Entry<K, V> o2) {
                return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
            }
        });

        //LinkedHashMap will keep the keys in the order they are inserted
        //which is currently sorted on natural ordering
        Map<K,V> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<K,V>();

        for(Map.Entry<K,V> entry: entries){
            sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

        return sortedMap;
    }

}
```

output would be..

```
Unsorted Map in Java : {USA=1, England=3, Russia=4, China=2}
Sorted Map in Java by key: {China=2, England=3, Russia=4, USA=1}
Sorted Map in Java by values: {USA=1, China=2, England=3, Russia=4}
Sorted Map in Java by key using TreeMap : {China=2, England=3, Russia=4, USA=1}
Example to sort Map in Java using Guava : {China=2, England=3, Russia=4, USA=1}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a `TreeMap`? It will keep your keys in sorted order.

Comment: @Brigham I have shown th//Sorting Map in Java by keys using TreeMap
        Map<String, Integer> sortedMapByKeys = new TreeMap<String,Integer>();
        sortedMapByKeys.putAll(olympic2012);
        System.out.println("Sorted Map in Java by key using TreeMap : " + sortedMapByKeys)

Comment: I think this question belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: So to be clear on what you're trying to do here, you want a process that takes a single `Map`, and results in two `Map`s, one sorted by key and one sorted by value?

Answer (score 2):

A better approach is to use `TreeMap` with a given comparator instead of "manual" sorting and putting results into a `LinkedHashMap`

Comment: i have already done that.

Comment: `TreeMap` can't sort by value, only by key. OP has both sorting methods.

Comment: You can sort by value, if you use comparator which looks up values in another map.